# how to fix ["failed to register ","Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf"]

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh

I am new to phonegap and I want to implement pushwoosh notification services but I cant get it right. Every time I call the registerPushwoosh() function I get this error.

I am using the SDK Sample Project -> Android Phonegap.

every time getting this error.

```
how to fix  ["failed to register ","Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf"]
```

here is image link [ERROR AND DIrectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyzqL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Emulator with a Google API.